# CoreData application directory crashes on iOS3

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, core-data

I have nearly finished my application that works well on iOS4, however when loading it into the 3.2 simulator it crashes with..

```
2010-12-21 07:54:32.052 App[14044:207] *** -[NSPathStore2 URLByAppendingPathComponent:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4d2b640
2010-12-21 07:54:32.054 App[14044:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSPathStore2 URLByAppendingPathComponent:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4d2b640'
```

I am getting the application Document Directory with

```
NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"App.sqlite"];

- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}
```

Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000301-SW28) mentions that `URLByAppendingPathComponent:` is only available in iOS 4 and later. You can accomplish the same thing by using `NSStrings` with [stringByAppendingPathComponent:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-stringByAppendingPathComponent_), and then converting to a URL when done.

Apparently `URLsForDirectory:inDomains:` is 4.0-only as well. Check out [NSSearchPathsForDirectoriesInDomains()](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000055-SW5) for an alternative that's compatible with earlier OSes.

Answer (score 9):

Used

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *myPathDocs =  [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"app.sqlite"];
NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:myPathDocs];
```

Thanks Justin

Answer (score 1):

For iOS3 compatibility change the method and caller to:

```
- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    return [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
}

NSString *storePath = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"App.sqlite"];
```

Model needs a change as well:

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (__managedObjectModel != nil) {
    return __managedObjectModel;
    }

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"App" ofType:@"momd"];  
    NSURL *modelURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

//  this was:    
//  NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"App" withExtension:@"momd"];

    __managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return __managedObjectModel;
}
```