# iphone - coredata application directory

Tags: iphone, core-data

I am using this Xcode template for core data.

On the delegate, I have this method:

```
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
  return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}
```

but this requires iOS4.

I am trying to make the app compatible with 3.0.

So, I have converted this method to:

```
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {

  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
  return [NSURL URLWithString:documentsDirectory];

}
```

but when coredata tries to use the store URL on

```
  NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyFile.sqlite"];
  if (![persistentStoreCoordinator_ addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
```

it crashes on the IF line with the message:

**CoreData SQL stores only support file URLs (got /var/mobile/Applications/BB312A7E-6AE1-4BA2-AD87-6B96D8855CC6/Documents/MyFile.sqlite).'**

but StoreURL is a NSURL!

Any clues? Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try doing:

```
NSString *pathToYourSqliteFile = @"/your/path/here";
NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: isDirectory:NO];
```

See if that does the trick.

Comment: My Apps Deployment target is 8.0 and this worked for it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

See [CoreData application directory crashes on iOS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497062/coredata-application-directory-crashes-on-ios3)

The suggestion from Surfdev works ok on 3.1.2

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3

```
 let documentsUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in:.userDomainMask).first!
```